# Error: not connected to mongos

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to create and populate a series of shards with mongo. However I keep getting the error below:

[image]

Error:not connected to mongos.

I have 'mongod' running in the background. Is this different to mongod? I have tried to run 'mongos' in the cmd line but this also gives me an error.

How do I get rid of this error?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I cant see your img

Comment: @ŞükranEken can you not see the image ?

Comment: @Nick can you not see the image either? I will try to fix this.

Comment: I have added the image a second time to the post

Comment: I cant see;but this is my problem your link is true.

Comment: @ŞükranEken  oh I understand. Not to worry. It is an image of the command line which reads:

Error:not connected to mongos 
Failed to load: Shard_collection.js

I am wondering do I need to load something else into mongo to work with mongos? Or change a setting? I have only worked with mongod before

Comment: You have 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @ŞükranEken 64bit

Comment: Look. is there c:data/db?

Comment: Yes :) and my collection files appear to be in here

Comment: Please copy error on cmd and paste here with code?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
type "help" for help
2018-04-06T19:56:44.762+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not connected to a mongos :
sh._checkMongos@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:8:15
sh._adminCommand@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:18:9
sh.enableSharding@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:98:12
@4.shard_collection.js:18:7
failed to load: 4.shard_collection.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear as though your cluster doesn't have all of the components required to function, so you will indeed need to have (amongst other things) at least 1 mongos instance running.

I would imagine (as there is no detail on the error you received when starting mongos) the reason you couldn't run the mongos daemon was because it's configured to run on the same port as mongod. So if you're attempting to run all the of the components on 1 machine, you will need to set different port numbers for each component.

`mongod` is the daemon which runs a MongoDB instance (the data store), and `mongos` is the router service for your cluster.

You will need:

- a number of `mongod` instances running as your shards (where the data is actually sorted)
- 3 `mongod` instances running as `config` servers (meta data of which shard contains which range of data (based on your shard keys)
- 1 or more `mongos` instances which are your routers - decides (based on information from the config servers) which shard(s) it needs to query & then handles sorting & merging of the results before returning the query results. Also, your `mongos` servers are the endpoints you actually connect to from your client.

When you have all of the components running, you will then need to connect to one of your `mongos` instances in order to initialise the shard, manage & query the data behind it.

In a standalone or replica-set configuration, you connect to one of the `mongod` instances in order to query it, manage it etc. In a Sharded cluster, you connect to one of the `mongos` instead which manages the routing of your queries.

This tutorial is pretty good & helped me a bunch when I was first playing with Sharded clusters

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/

Comment: This is a huge help - Thank you so much for your detailed answer I will definitely study this tutorial :)  When you say mongos are like routers, am I correct in saying you don't run these in the cmd like mongod and use to query? Mongos are something which runs in the background, so opening a cmd window and simply typing 'mongos' will not work?

Comment: Correct. both mongod & mongos are daemons which run in the background. 

You connect & query a sharded cluster in exactly the same way as you always have `mongo <host or ip> port` or from your app with `mongodb://<host or ip>:<port>/db_name....` but instead of connecting to the host and/or port which mongod is running on, you connect to the host and/or port which mongos is running on